# npm install -g aws-sdk yet aws-sdk not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, aws-sdk, npm-install

I've installed aws-sdk in an ubuntu 20.04 container as follows:

`sudo npm install -g aws-sdk`

The, when running a script that requires the package, I get:

`Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'`

Why can't it find my package?  What am I doing wrong?  Installing with `-g` but without `sudo` fails with permission errors.

Any help or hints welcome.

Comment: Since you had installed globally a system restart or editor restart should work. Else use "npm install aws-sdk". Install it locally and should work.

Comment: is `aws-sdk` listed when you run `npm list -g --depth=0`?

Comment: When I run `npm list -g --depth=0`, I see `aws-sdk` listed. But when I run `which aws-sdk`, I get `aws-sdk not found`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link the global module to your project by executing:-

```
npm link aws-sdk
```

in your project's root directory provided you have aws-sdk globally installed.

`npm link <package-name>` will create a symbolic link from globally-installed package-name to `node_modules/` of the current folder.

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link

Comment: This changed nothing for me.